# torch error of accessing weights of a neural network model built by multiple layer perceptrons

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, torch

I am trying to access weights of a neural network model built by torch on databricks.

the code :

```
 import torch
 import torch.nn as nn
 import numpy 

 class Feedforward(nn.Module):

     def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size):
         super(Feedforward, self).__init__()
         self.input_size = input_size
         self.hidden_size  = hidden_size
         self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.input_size, self.hidden_size)
         self.relu = nn.ReLU()
         self.fc2 = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, 1)
         self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

     def forward(self, x):
         hidden = self.fc1(x)
         relu = self.relu(hidden)
         output = self.fc2(relu)
         output = self.sigmoid(output)
         return output

from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
def blob_label(y, label, loc): # assign labels
    target = numpy.copy(y)
    for l in loc:
        target[y == l] = label
    return target

x_train, y_train = make_blobs(n_samples=40, n_features=2, cluster_std=1.5, shuffle=True)
x_train = torch.FloatTensor(x_train)
y_train = torch.FloatTensor(blob_label(y_train, 0, [0]))
y_train = torch.FloatTensor(blob_label(y_train, 1, [1,2,3]))

x_test, y_test = make_blobs(n_samples=10, n_features=2, cluster_std=1.5, shuffle=True)
x_test = torch.FloatTensor(x_test)
y_test = torch.FloatTensor(blob_label(y_test, 0, [0]))
y_test = torch.FloatTensor(blob_label(y_test, 1, [1,2,3]))

model = Feedforward(2, 10)
criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.01)

y_pred = model(x_test)
before_train = criterion(y_pred.squeeze(), y_test)
print('Test loss before training' , before_train.item())

model.train()
epoch = 20
for epoch in range(epoch):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    # Forward pass
    y_pred = model(x_train)
    # Compute Loss
    loss = criterion(y_pred.squeeze(), y_train)

print('Epoch {}: train loss: {}'.format(epoch, loss.item()))
# Backward pass
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()

model.eval()
y_pred = model(x_test)
after_train = criterion(y_pred.squeeze(), y_test) 
print('Test loss after Training' , after_train.item())
```

The code works well. But, when I tried to access the weights of the model, I got error:

```
 model.weight # ModuleAttributeError: 'Feedforward' object has no attribute 'weight'
```

But, if I tried

```
model.fc1.weight
```

it works well..

How to access the weights of a model built by multiple layer perceptron ?

This post [Can't init the weights of my neural network PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59156629/cant-init-the-weights-of-my-neural-network-pytorch)
does not work for me.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since it's `nn.Linear()` that has the attribute, and not `Feedforward`, try changing

```
class Feedforward(nn.Module):

     def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size):
         super(Feedforward, self).__init__()
         self.input_size = input_size
         self.hidden_size  = hidden_size
         self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.input_size, self.hidden_size)
         self.relu = nn.ReLU()
         self.fc2 = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, 1)
         self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
```

to

```
class Feedforward(nn.Module):

     def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size):
         super(nn.Linear, self).__init__()
         self.input_size = input_size
         self.hidden_size  = hidden_size
         self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.input_size, self.hidden_size)
         self.relu = nn.ReLU()
         self.fc2 = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size, 1)
         self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your suggestions. I got error "TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type". thanks